# How to change the Highchart plotline color for theme

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am trying to make a chart where the plotline is by default white in color.
Now, when changing the theme of the page, I want to change the plotline color from whtie to black for light theme. Here is my code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        type: 'line'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],

        plotLines: [{
            color: '#FFF',
            width: 2,
            value: 5.5,
            dashStyle: 'dash'
        }]
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

[image: chart]

on the image the plotline is white, but I want it to be black only when changing the light theme.
Suggestion please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Highcharts we've got something that is called themes. We've got plenty of them and you can find them here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/ts/masters/themes

I also suggest reading about creating your own theme, which is something that I believe you're looking for: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/themes#creating-your-own-theme

Demo of creating a theme that is similar to the one from your image: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g05sancb/

```
Highcharts.theme = {
 chart: {
  backgroundColor: '#000'
 },
 xAxis: {
  plotLines: [{
   color: '#FFF',
   width: 2,
   value: 5.5,
   dashStyle: 'dash'
 }]
}};
```